# php with html question about lines and returns

Tags: php, html

I want the php/html to be like this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="
<?php if
```

But if you write it this way there is a carriage return so it puts a return in the html and that is not the best.

You can write it this way with no carriage return. But the php does not look as organized.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php
if
```

Is there a more proper way, a better way?

Comment: Can you please explain what's the purpose of adding `if` inside href? Simply to decide which style to use?

Answer (score 5):

Avoid nesting `if` inside html tag, especially if you have block of if conditions, since it does not look neat and it'll be harder to debug the code. I'd prefer to keep them separated.

```
<?php 
  if (condition1)$style = 'css/style1.css';
  else if (condition2)$style = 'css/style2.css';
  else $style = 'css/default.css';  
?>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $style;?>" > 
</head>
```

Comment: At first I looked at this and thought that's a good idea. But, then no. Your idea is nice but not tightly efficient; due to needing 3 sections of code to do one function. The 3rd part being the condition part; so actually more than 3 parts if you count all the conditions being separate?... The way I wrote it there is only 1 part of code and that was the objective mostly.

Comment: Actually I solved my question. Its better to use some echo statements with single quotes. This way it removes the returns.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of formatting conundrum is frequently a pain point w/ dynamic HTML generation. This can be significantly lessened by using a templating system like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), but shy of that, I'd recommend migrating to a more view-like design by generating the dynamic block elsewhere, and then just passing the value to your echo statement. Ideally, the value would be calculated in a model and then passed to a view via a controller, but if you've got a more monolithic design, you can sort of fake it by putting your logic outside the HTML block:

```
<?php
    // a bunch of code to calculate what should be in $foo
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?= $foo ?>">
```

Comment: I don't like this method. I would imagine there are other print commands that could do the html code more tightly with php, and more efficiently in one single code string. That is what I am thinking.

Comment: Actually I solved my question. Its better to use some echo statements with single quotes. This way it removes the returns.